# Pre-Populate template field with default value from model in Django/Wagtail

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

I want to add a default value and have it populate the field in a Wagtail template based on a Django model. I know I am returning the value because if I populate 'help-text' attribute with this value, it works but I cannot get it populate the field with the default attribute. I am using a field panel for the content panel. This Class is very long so I did not post the whole thing.

```
def live_video_url():
    return constants.streaming_info['live-video-captions']


class MeetingPage(Page):
    live_video_url = models.URLField(
        default=live_video_url, 
        blank=False, 
        help_text=live_video_url, 
        null=True
    )
    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('live_video_url'),
    ]
```

I am getting this in the actual field in the Wagtail editor, but the correct url string in help-text:

```
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x104547470>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue as you seem to be saying that it's the field value itself that is rendering incorrectly, but `help_text` does not accept a callable the way you are passing one. It needs to be a string.

Comment: the help-text does work wether I render it as a string or as the return from the callable:
either of these work :return str(constants.streaming_info['live-video-captions']) -or- return constants.streaming_info['live-video-captions']

Comment: Where and how are `constants` defined? Can you add this to your question?

Comment: The `null=True` can't be right. You should not use null on string fields. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#null

Answer (score 0):

Example of adding a default value in a field in the wagtail admin

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm


class MyItemForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        description = self.fields["description"]
        description.widget.attrs["value"] = "My new initial data"


class MyItem(Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("description"),
    ] 

    base_form_class = MyItemForm
```